# GoogleApps scripting: Find a line in an e-mail body and extract a name at the end of the line

Tags: regex, string, google-apps-script

Find the line in an e-mail body which contains two keywords and then extract a name at the end of the line.
e.g. Find the line containing "Gereserveerd door:" and extract the name that follows e.g. "Hessel van Hoorn".
The line in this case is "Gereserveerd door:    Nicole Vermeulen" including the spaces.

I am new to GoogleApps scripting, but I know various other programming and scripting languages.
I hope someone can help.

I was looking for methods to acomplish this, but didn't find any.